# How can I make AWS lambda find the grpc dependency in my function?

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-lambda-layers

GRPC is giving me fits here:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Could not find 'grpc' (~> 1.24) among 281 total gem(s)\nChecked in 'GEM_PATH=/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0:/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0:/var/runtime', execute `gem env` for more information",
  "errorType": "Init<Gem::MissingSpecError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1402:in `block in activate_dependencies'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `each'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `activate_dependencies'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1373:in `activate'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:215:in `rescue in try_activate'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:208:in `try_activate'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:161:in `rescue in require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'",
    "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/google-cloud-dialogflow-0.14.0/lib/google/cloud/dialogflow.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/task/google_dialog.rb:3:in `require_relative'",
    "/var/task/google_dialog.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `rescue in require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'"
  ]
}
```

I see it at `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/grpc-1.27.0-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc.rb`

I'm writing a simple Ruby class to hook into Dialogflow, and the google gem is fairly heavy with a lot of dependencies.  I've written some tests that all pass locally and in the context of the Rails application from where I'm extracting this bit of code.  I'll need Nokogiri, but it appears that Google is the big user of the GRPC stuff.  And it just won't find that file when when I specify is manually.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the above issue - order of operations are everything I learned.  Ruby is parsing top-down instead of loading everything then parsing, which I suppose I should have known, but Rails does a lot of magical things for you.

So when I was seeing the issue above, I had the following require statements at the top of my file:

```
require_relative 'vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/lib/nokogiri.rb'
require_relative 'vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/google-cloud-dialogflow-0.14.0/lib/google/cloud/dialogflow.rb'
require_relative 'vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/google-cloud-dialogflow-0.14.0/lib/google/cloud/dialogflow/v2.rb'
require_relative 'vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/grpc-1.24.0-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc.rb'
```

And due to the require for grpc coming after the google cloud ruby

```
require_relative 'vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/grpc-1.24.0-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc.rb'
require_relative 'vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/lib/nokogiri.rb'
require_relative 'vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/google-cloud-dialogflow-0.14.0/lib/google/cloud/dialogflow.rb'
require_relative 'vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/google-cloud-dialogflow-0.14.0/lib/google/cloud/dialogflow/v2.rb'
```

Simply putting grpc before dialogflow resolved that issue.

Lesson - always go back to basics.